# Facing issues with Animator and Animation APIs in Android for visual effects

Tags: android, animation, animator

Our team is developing an educational app. It will be available for international users. We are planning to make app rich with more visual effects. Most of the view objects will be animated.

But while developing prototype we faced some issues with Animator and Animation APIs in Android. Like, elements using Animator API will not be animated while battery saver mode is on. As a temporary solution we have used [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library which provide the same Animator APIs but works fine while battery saver mode is on.

Animation API animate views perfectly even battery saver mode is on but does move view object fully. It just draws the view object as per the animations. So the x & y location, pivot x & y, etc. and `onClick` events is still pointing out to last position where the view object firstly got generated. Thus, we are not able to continue with a new animation from the current position.

Even though we are not developing a game app, we need your help to understand how we can create game like visual effects and transitions on views. Because views need to be visually animated to make users understand the current functionality in order to move forward.